# ajax response not proper binding in select option value jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

- I'm trying to get value from ajax to HTML but it's not correctly binding in the dropdown even I tried in the textbox it's not showing. I tried to add some static value it's also not showing.
- Ajax response is properly getting in the console but when I am trying to bind in the HTML its not show proper.

[image]

- HTML code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="largeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title1" id="defaultModalLabel"></h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
               <label>Room Type</label>
               <h1 class="modal-title1" ></h1>
               <!-- <input type="text" class="apple"> -->
               <select class="apple" tabindex="-98">
                  <option>-Select Room type-</option>
               </select>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                  <input class="btn  btn-lg bg-indigo waves-effect" type="submit" value="SAVE">
                  <button class="btn  btn-lg bg-black waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">CLOSE</button>    
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

- JQuery code:

```
$(document).off('click', '.hotel_add').on('click', '.hotel_add', function () {
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var pos = $(this).closest('.hotel-result').data('pos-id');
$.get("<?php echo base_url('hotel/hotelDataGet') ?>/" + id + '/' + pos, function (result) {
var data = JSON.parse(result)
$.each(data,function(index,value){
console.log(value);
$('#defaultModalLabel').html(value.hotel_name);
$('.apple').append('
<option value="'+value['roomtype']+'">'+value['roomtype']+'</option>
');
});
$("#largeModal").modal();
//debugger;  
});
});
```

- AJAX response

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "hotel_name": "Hotel Bharat",
    "room_type": "4,1,2",
    "cp_price": "98"
  },
  {
    "roomtype": "Deluxe Room"
  },
  {
    "roomtype": "Luxury Room"
  },
  {
    "roomtype": "Family room"
  }
]
```

Comment: $.each is looping through each object and the first object didnot have the roomtype property. You have to change the AJAX response format. Use array for roomtype property and loop through that array.

Comment: Response is perfect but its not proper  binding in HTML dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hotel_name` only exists on the first object of your response, and the `roomtype` does not exist in your fist object, so you can change to this:

```
$.each(data,function(index,value){
     //check to see if this object has the property "hotel_name"
     if(value.hasOwnProperty("hotel_name"){
         $('#defaultModalLabel').html(value.hotel_name);
     }
     //check to see if this object has the property "roomtype"
     if(value.hasOwnProperty("roomtype") {
         $('.apple').append(
             '<option value="' +
              value['roomtype'] + 
              '">' +
              value['roomtype'] +
              '</option>'
         );
      }
});
```

Comment: The response is perfect but still not proper showing dropdown, Thanks for your suggestion now response is proper but HTML not proper formating

Comment: Please see 1st screenshot, i got values in the popup, but see that the incorrect format

Comment: @JaydevVara This answer works for me: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wx2h9uf6/1/)

Comment: yes its working fine, but that value is not binding proper for me, that dropdown is modal

Comment: please see 1st screenshot

Comment: yes i saw, your fiddle, That's 100% correct, might be a problem in my HTML Css

Comment: @JaydevVara Yes, it may be problem in your HTML/CSS. The script is working in my example. Which I can't help you with as that isn't part of your post or question. You may also need to try clearing your browser cache as your script file may be cached in your browser with the previous version.